# So, "in 5 minutes" means either "during 5 minutes" or "after 5 minutes" right?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

[Cambridge Grammar said:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time)

> We use **in** to say how long it takes someone to do something:
>
> *He was such a clever musician. He could learn a song in about five minutes.*
>
> We use an apostrophe -s construction (in a year’s time, in two months’
>   time) to say when something will happen. We don’t use it to say how
>   long someone takes to do something:
>
> *I won’t say goodbye because we’ll be seeing each other again in three days’ time.* We can also say in three days, without time, in this
>   example.
>
> *He ran the marathon in six hours and 20 minutes.*
>
> Not: *He ran the marathon in six hours and 20 minutes’ time.*

[In oxford dictionary,](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/in_1?q=in)

> in:- **during a period of time**
>
> in 2009
>
> in the 18th century
>
> in spring/summer/autumn/winter
>
> in the fall
>
> in March
>
> in the morning/afternoon/evening
>
> I'm getting forgetful in my old age.
>
> in:- **after a particular length of time**
>
> to return in a few minutes/hours/days/months.
>
> It will be ready in a week's time (= one week from now).
>
> She learnt to drive in three weeks (= after three weeks she could
>   drive).

so, Does Cambridge Grammar mean?

*He could learn a song in about five minutes*.=*He could learn a song during about five minutes*.?

&

*we’ll be seeing each other again in three days’ time*= *we’ll be seeing each other again after three days*?

So, "**in 5 minutes**" means either "**during 5 minutes**" or "**after 5 minutes**" right?

Comment: With respect to your paraphrase: **during five minutes**,  **during five weeks**,  etc are not idiomatic as is. When using the preposition **during** with a *number* of time-units, you need a noun, the span, that comprises those time-units: "during a *space* of five minutes" or "during a brief *respite* of five weeks" or "during three weeks *of the semester*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oxford's definition, "after a particular length of time" can be thought of as "after a particular length of time **has elapsed**."

So:

> He will return in a few days time.

basically means:

> He will return after a few days have gone by.

---

As for:

> He could learn a song in about five minutes.

a good substitution preposition for this would be ***within***:

> He could learn a song within five minutes.

Another way we could convey this is:

> It took him no longer than five minutes to learn a song.

---

As for *during*, think of that as "**at some point in time during a specified interval**".

Therefore:

> My daughter was born in January.

means:

> My daughter was born on some day in January.

And:

> Hurricane Katrina happened in 2005.

means:

> Hurricane Katrina happened on some day during 2005.

---

**Bottom Line**: in cases where *in* means *during*, that doesn't mean within some interval of time (such as *in five minutes*, or *in two days*), but rather for a more specific range of time (such as *in the first week of the month, in December*, or *in the 18th century*, or even *in the early hours of the morning*).

Comment: I misunderstood "during". So, during can mean "*at some point in a period of time*" (He was taken to the hospital during the night.) or 
"*all through a period of time*" (Please remain seated during the performance.)

Comment: @Tom - Yes, exactly. And those are two good examples of each of those meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the preposition **in** when used with dates and time has three general meanings:

1. **During** *(during part or all of a period of time)*
2. **No more than** *(needing or using no more time than a particular amount of time)*
3. **Before the end** *(before or at the end of a particular period)*

Oxford's definition **"after a particular length of time"** is probably unfinished because *"in"* in most cases means *"within the limits of a time period"*. *After/afterwards* means *"following"*.

- to return in a few minutes/hours/days/months. - *to return in a no longer time than a few minutes/hours/days/months.*
- It will be ready in a week's time - *it will be ready before or at the end of one week.*
- She learnt to drive in three weeks - *it took her no more than three weeks to learn to drive.*

Examples with your phrase *"in 5 minutes"*:

- I'll be back in five minutes. = *It won't take me more than five minutes to return. or I'll be back before five minutes pass.*
- I can smoke two cigarettes in five minutes. = *A period of time (five minutes) is enough for me to smoke two cigarettes.*
- I can finish this in one day. = *I need no more than a day to finish this.*
- The cake will ready in 15 minutes. = *The cake will be ready before 15 minutes elapse.*