# Is there any difference in meaning or usage between "four weeks from today" and "in four weeks"?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning or usage between "four week from today" and "in four weeks"? For example:

> What are you guys doing **four weeks from today**?
>
> What are you guys doing **in four weeks**?

I cannot see any difference between the two. If there is any, could you tell me which one is more common?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time Expressions with "in"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208621/time-expressions-with-in) See also [So, “in 5 minutes” means either “during 5 minutes” or “after 5 minutes” right?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126581/so-in-5-minutes-means-either-during-5-minutes-or-after-5-minutes-right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Four weeks from today* implies 'in exactly 28 days' time', while *in four weeks* could be less exact.

Answer (score 1):

**"A week from today"** (idiom) means *"in one week"*.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20week%20from%20today

Therefore, **"four weeks from today"** and **"in four weeks"** are synonymous and interchangeable, IMHO.

Comment: I would agree with Kate’s answer: four weeks from today means _exactly_ 28 days.